# Когда мне следует использовать javascript шаблонизаторы

Tags: javascript, шаблонизаторы

Когда мне следует использовать javascript шаблонизаторы? Бывают ли ситуации когда они критически важны?

Answer (score 2):

Странный вопрос. Шаблонизация нужна в том месте, где у вас есть данные и на основе их нужно построить страницу или её часть. Например на нашем проекте, backend отдаёт только json и минимальную обвязку, всё остальное строится прямо на клиенте.

Comment: Но ведь я могу обойтись и без него. Вопрос в том когда действительно оправдано подключать все эти handlebars и т.п.

Comment: Конечно можете, только это не удобно, не гибко, а html пихать в js так совсем не красиво. + Многие шаблонизаторы давно уже предлагают не просто генерацию html, но и data-binding и многое другое. Я с трудом представляю, как можно сделать Single Page App без шаблонизации.